# $n\nmid(nk\pm r)$ where $n\in(1,\infty)\cap\mathbb{N},k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0<r<n$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

> a) [Prove that for any natural number $n>1$ and $k, n\nmid(kn+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3362063)
>
> b) We like to extend the result in part $(a)$. Given a number $n$, assume $0< r < n$, $r$ is a natural number, then $n\nmid(nk\pm r)$.

b) Proof.

(Note: $\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{Z^+}$)

$$\text{WTS }\forall n\in(1,\infty)\cap \mathbb{N}, k\in\mathbb{N}, r\in((-n,n)\backslash\{0\})\cap\mathbb{Z}, c \in \mathbb{N}, kn+r \neq cn$$

Prove this by contradiction,if not then we have the following:

$$\exists n\in(1,\infty)\cap \mathbb{N}, k\in\mathbb{N}, r\in((-n,n)\backslash\{0\})\cap\mathbb{Z}, c \in \mathbb{N}, kn+r = cn$$

Have

$$n(c-k)=r$$

That $c-k \neq 0$ otherwise $r=0$, then we have:$$n=\frac{r}{c-k}$$

But $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(c-k)\in\mathbb{Z}$, implies $|r|\ge n$

If not we have $$|r|<n$$$$|r|<\frac{r}{c-k}$$

And this implies $c-k\in(-1,1)\backslash\{0\}\Rightarrow c-k\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ , That $c\not\in\mathbb{Z}\vee k\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, contradiction!

By contradiction, it must be the case that $|r|\ge n$, which again contradict with the assumption. $\square$

---

$1.$Is my proof correct

$2.$Is there better ways to prove this

Any help or hint or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that if $0 < a < b$ then $0 < \frac ab < 1$ and there are no integers between $0$ and $1$?  And *surely* we are allowed to assume $\mathbb Q$ is field with the division property that if $c \ne 0$ then $ac = bc \iff a=b$, correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that's right, those are questions for UTM "A Readable Introduction to Real Mathmatics" chapter 1-3, but another question in my problem set says we can not use division yet, i'm kind of confused...  @fleablood

Comment: If you can't use division then you can't use division.  So my proof (which was going to be if $mn = kn + 1$ then $\frac 1n = m-k$ which is an integer) would not be acceptable. But in an introduction we can *not* assume that for $c\ne 0$ that $ac=bc\implies a=b$ (although we can assume the other direction) or, I suppose, we can't assume the integers are closed under addition. We *do* have to do our proofs in the context of the course (which will, presumably, eventually allow division).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is pretty much correct except stylistically you have used too many quantifiers and not much prose. It will be hard for someone to follow what you are doing.

As far as can it be done differently? I think it can. So here is another approach.

Using proof by contradiction method. Suppose there is a $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $n \mid nk \pm r$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $r \in \{1,2,3, \ldots ,n-1\}$. Since $n \mid nk \pm r$ and $n \mid nk$, and we have
$$\pm r=(nk \pm r)-nk.$$
Therefore $n$ will divide $\pm r$ also. This means $n \leq |r|$. But $|r| \leq n-1$, which means $n \leq n-1$, a contradiction.